# Show that $\operatorname{int} (\operatorname{bd} (A)) = ∅$ if and only if $\operatorname{bd} (\operatorname{bd} (A)) = \operatorname{bd} (A)$

Tags: general-topology

If (S,T) be a topology space and $A$ be a subset of $S$ and $\operatorname{bd}(A) = \overline{A} ∩ \overline{A^c}   $ Show that $\operatorname{int} (\operatorname{bd} (A)) = ∅$ if and only if $\operatorname{bd} (\operatorname{bd} (A)) = \operatorname{bd} (A)$

Comment: Can you find a relation between $int(B)$ and $\overline{B^c}$ to write $bd(B)$ in terms of $\overline{B}$ and $int(B)$? That would make it quick.

Comment: @DanielFischer I find that $(int (A))^c = \overline {A^c}$ if that's help.

Comment: Good. And if you use that, the expression for the boundary becomes $bd(B) = \overline{B}\setminus int(B)$. Can you see how that makes this simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As intersection of two closed sets $\partial A$ is closed, so that
$\partial\left(\partial A\right)=\partial A-\text{int}\left(\partial A\right)$.

Based on this it is immediate that $\text{int}\left(\partial A\right)=\varnothing\implies\partial A=\partial\left(\partial A\right)$.

If conversely $a\in\text{int}\left(\partial A\right)\subseteq\partial A$
then $a\notin\partial A-\text{int}\left(\partial A\right)=\partial\left(\partial A\right)$
so $\partial A\neq\partial\left(\partial A\right)$.